# DDEV not serving Symfony Mercure-Hub over HTTPS

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ddev, mercure

I am running a Symfony Project via `drud/ddev` (nginx) for local development.
I did this many times before and had no issues whatsoever.

In my recent project I have to use the [Mercure-Hub](https://github.com/dunglas/mercure) to push Notifications from the server to the client.
I required the `symfony/mercure-bundle` via composer and copied the generated docker-compose content into a `docker-compose.mercure.yaml` (`.ddev/docker-compose.mercure.yaml`)
After starting the container the Mercure-Hub works seamlessly but is only reachable over http.

*My problem: I only have beginner knowledge in the field of nginx and docker-compose.*

I am thankful for every bit of advice! :)

### Steps to reproduce

1. Setup basic Symfony Project and run it via DDEV.
2. Require `symfony/mercure-bundle`.
3. Copy `docker-compose.yaml` and `docker-compose.override.yaml` content to a `docker-compose.mercure.yaml` in the `.ddev` folder (change the port).
4. Configure Mercure-Hub URL in `.env`.
5. Start the container and visit `[DDEV-URL]:[MERCURE-PORT]` / subscribe a Mercure topic.

### My problem

- Mercure-Hub only reachable via http.
- HTTPS call gets an `'ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR'`

### My wish

- Access the Mercure-Hub URL / subscribe to Mercure topics via HTTPS.

### What I've tried

- Reading the [Mercure-Hub Docs](https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config) and trying to adapt the Docker SSL / HTTPS instructions to my local drud/ddev environment
- Adding another server to the nginx configuration as in the Mercure-Cookbook "[Using NGINX as an HTTP/2 Reverse Proxy in Front of the Hub](https://github.com/dunglas/mercure/blob/main/docs/hub/cookbooks.md)"
- Googling a bunch
- Hours of trial and error

## Files

### ddev config.yaml

```
name: project-name
type: php
docroot: public
php_version: "8.1"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: true
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database:
  type: mariadb
  version: "10.4"
nfs_mount_enabled: true
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
nodejs_version: "16"
```

### docker-compose.mercure.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  ###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ':3000'
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      # Set the URL of your Symfony project (without trailing slash!) as value of the cors_origins directive
      MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
        cors_origins http://127.0.0.1:8000
    # Comment the following line to disable the development mode
    command: /usr/bin/caddy run -config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
    volumes:
      - mercure_data:/data
      - mercure_config:/config
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

volumes:
  ###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure_data:
  mercure_config:
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
```

### .env

```
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
# See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html#configuration

# The URL of the Mercure hub, used by the app to publish updates (can be a local URL)
MERCURE_URL=http://ddev-pnp-master-mercure-1:3000/.well-known/mercure

# The public URL of the Mercure hub, used by the browser to connect
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://ddev-pnp-master-mercure-1:3000/.well-known/mercure

# The secret used to sign the JWTs
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET="!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!"

###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
```

---

### Edit 1

I changed my docker-compose thanks to the advice from rfay.
(only showing the relevant part below)

```
[...]
services:
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "3000"
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=":3000"
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=9998:3000
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=9999:3000
[...]
```

- replaced `ports` with `expose`
- added `HTTP_EXPOSE` & `HTTPS_EXPOSE`

#### Problem with this

Now my problem is that the container doesn't expose any ports (see docker desktop screenshot below).

[docker desktop port screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIQ5v.png)

Comment: Hi - You should be using HTTP_EXPOSE and HTTPS_EXPOSE to get your port exposed with TLS, not using `ports`. Use `expose` instead of `ports` and then add `HTTP_EXPOSE` and `HTTPS_EXPOSE`. There are many examples; use `ddev get --list` to see some supported services, and see the docs at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#docker-composeyaml-examples

Comment: @rfay Hi, thanks for the advice! I changed my docker-compose but now the container doesn't expose any port. (see "Edit 1")

Comment: With your updated situation, ddev-router will bind to ports 9999 and 9998, making them available. And your mercure container will be listening on port 3000 (http only) for in-docker requests.  But I see you forgot `- VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME`

Comment: Adding `- VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME` fixed it! I must have overlooked it. Thank you for helping me!Do you want to write an answer so I can upvote it? Or should I write my own answer? (I am new to using stackoverflow for anything other than only reading)

Comment: I'd say go ahead and write your own answer. Please make sure to link to the docs. Note that if you think this recipe is valuable to others (or to more than one project you maintain) then you may want to make a ddev add-on, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/#creating-an-additional-service-for-ddev-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

With the help of rfay I found the solution (which consisted of reading the [ddev documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#docker-composeyaml-examples) properly lol).

### What I did

- replacing `ports` with `expose`
- adding `VIRTUAL_HOST`, `HTTP_EXPOSE` and `HTTPS_EXPOSE` under `environment`
- adding `container_name` & `labels` (see code below)

### My final docker-compose.mercure.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: "ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-mercure-hub"
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: ${DDEV_APPROOT}
    expose:
      - "3000"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: $DDEV_HOSTNAME
      SERVER_NAME: ":3000"
      HTTP_EXPOSE: "9998:3000"
      HTTPS_EXPOSE: "9999:3000"
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
        cors_origins https://project-name.ddev.site
    # Comment the following line to disable the development mode
    command: /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
    volumes:
      - mercure_data:/data
      - mercure_config:/config

volumes:
  mercure_data:
  mercure_config:
```

With this docker-compose in place my mercure container is available via HTTPS over the port `9999`.

**For further information see the ddev documentation:** https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#docker-composeyaml-examples

Comment: Thx a lot! This soulition gave me some tips in my problem with symfony app + nginx + docker - the solution was to expose ports.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735903/21252828 does not work until you add a minus before the config option at the command:

```
...
command: /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
...
```

Otherwise the container fails (and restarts endless).

Maybe you can edit your post Christian Neugebauer?

Comment: Weird, for me starting the container works with one dash as well as two. Which version of dunglas/mercure are you using? I am using v0.14.2 at the moment. Maybe this is only relevant in a newer version?

Comment: I just tested this with version v0.14.5 and it seems you are right! I will edit my solution, thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This sort of feedback is normally handled via comments rather than answers.